# Generalizing the Capacitor Charging Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, charge, electrical-resistance, capacitance

We derived in class that the equation for the charging of a capacitor in series with a resistor is going to be:

$$q(t) = C\mathcal E \left(1-\exp \bigg \{ \frac{-t}{RC} \bigg \}\right)$$

This was derived for the case of a capacitor in the form:

[image]

Assuming no, I'm wondering if it is the case that this works for a general capacitor. Imagine we isolate a capacitor and resistor in series in a circuit and take $\epsilon$ to be something like the net voltage outside the capacitor. Would this work?

Or is my equation sadly only relevant for this little configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$q(t)=C\epsilon\left(1-\exp\left\{\frac{-t}{RC}\right\}\right)$$
works for capacitors which have zero charge on them at $t=0.$ If something interrupts the charge continuity, such as a sudden change in $R$ or $\epsilon$, the charge on the capacitor will not be zero and that will modify what happens.

On the other hand, the general behavior will still be an "inverse" exponential ($1-e^{f(t)}$) climb to the new maximum charge level, starting at the charge present when the sudden change happened.

And yes, this is the behavior for each capacitor buried down inside a DC circuit.  Exactly what $R$ and $C$ should be can get complicated with a network of capacitors and resistors, but the general behavior is true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on this, what would you choose for $\epsilon$? Additionally, how are super complex circuits analyzed? Doing the systems of  differential equations by hand would be too tedious.

Comment: You might want to read up on the way the SPICE works - start for example with [yhese lecture notes](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/7292571.PDF)

Comment: I agree with @Floris. You don't "choose" $\epsilon.$ You have to study the circuit, make combinations if possible, do it step by step. Not every circuit can be reduced to something simple (consider bridge circuits).  And few real circuits consist *only* of batteries, resistors and capacitors.  Once you move to non-constant voltage supplies, the time behaviors of RC networks are not like this. They become frequency dependent filters.